# Why do the tests not run using this gradle script

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Using: Android Studio 1.1.0; Gradle (in built)

I'm trying to create unit tests and run them. I created an example project (Calculator type deal) with some tests. Ran the tests from the IDE and they worked correctly. I tried to do the same from the console because the ultimate aim is to run these on a integration server, but the tests don't run. Why are the tests not run from the console? Does this gradle script have errors?

Sorry for the long post. Better is to give excess data than less. I'm a total of one day old in gradle. And yes, the jacoco task is because I want coverage next. As of now I see empty reports because the tests are not running I suppose.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

test {
    testLogging {
        events 'started', 'passed'
    }
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/reports"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I use this command to start the test

```
./gradlew test
```

This is the report I get

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preCompileDebugUnitTestJava
:app:compileDebugUnitTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugUnitTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebugUnitTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:testDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preCompileReleaseUnitTestJava
:app:compileReleaseUnitTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseUnitTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleReleaseUnitTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:testRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:test UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 10.288 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

`:<module>:test UP-TO-DATE` is because there have been no changes in the inputs/outputs of your project to trigger a rebuild.

If you want to force a test run, you can cleanup test results before you run tests. `clean<Task>` is a special task that cleans up the output of a task.

`./gradlew cleanTest test`

There are also other options, if you want tests to *always* run, you can force them to never be `UP TO DATE` by modifying the task's configuration. In your `build.gradle` file, try:

```
test {
  outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your inputs, but adding the "cleanTest" param did not work. Situation is still same as before. I also updated the build.gradle's task with what you mentioned, rebuilt and ran the test task, but the tests still don't run.

Comment: where are your tests defined?

Comment: perhaps you need to cleanup the outputs from `testRelease` and `testDebug` as those appear to be the actual testing tasks: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

Comment: source code is in: `src/main/java/` and tests are in: `src/test/java/`. The link you gave is a massive help for a noob. Concise and not having to wade in tons of data. As I read the page, I'm getting the feeling that it's not gradle which is at fault, my directory structure is somehow wrong. Thx